# sum of numbers in array not working

Tags: javascript

I have some array like this:

```
state = {
  array: [
    {
      id1,
      name1,
      price1
    },
    {
      id2,
      name2,
      price2
    },
    {
      id3,
      name3,
      price3
    }
  ]
}
```

and then I'm trying to sum the prices.

First I tried -

```
for (let key in arrayCopy) {
   totals += this.state.array[key].price;
}
```

2nd I've tried =

```
for (let key in arrayCopy) {
   total[key] = this.state.array[key].price;
}
var totals = total.reduce((a,b) => a + b,0);
```

I will try to explain it with numbers. For example:

```
price1 = 1000
price2 = 2000
price3 = 5000
```

I'm trying to get the total result by summing all the prices.

```
totals = price1 + price2 + price3
totals = 8000
```

but the result that I got is:

```
totals = 100020005000
```

Can someone please point out what I did wrong?

Comment: you have `price1`,`price2`..and you are accessing `this.state.array[key].price;` ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `price` is a `string` rather than a `number`, you will need to convert it to number first.

```
var totals = this.state.array.reduce((a,b)=>a+Number(b), 0);
```

Comment: @torazaburo sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce Array prototype method is sufficient

```
 let items = [{id:1,name:'s', price:100},{id:2,name:'sew',price:50},{ id:3, name:'se',price:10}];

 let sum = items.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b.price, 0);

 console.log(sum);
```

Comment: I have been updated my answer please check its helpful for u.